# Can't push to GitHub error: pack-objects died of signal 13

Tags: git, github

I'm having trouble pushing my local folder to my remote repository on GitHub.

After I push it gets to around 96% then shows this..

```
Counting objects: 4145, done.
Delta compression using up to 2 threads.
Connection to github.com closed by remote host.
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
Compressing objects:  98% (3919/3969)
```

Then after the last 2% completes is shows this error...

```
Compressing objects: 100% (3963/3963), done.
error: pack-objects died of signal 13
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@github.com:example/example.git'
```

Unsure what that means.

Comment: "git prune" worked for me.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This might be caused by the new [GitHub limits on file sizes](https://github.com/blog/1533-new-file-size-limits), or possibly the packing process is crashing out due to large data (like in this other SO question from 2011: [Alternative way to do an initial push of a large repo](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8672949/438886)) before those particular limits can even be reported.

A few weeks ago on a colleague's Mac OS X machine I saw a similar opaque error messag when pushing (tho' only over HTTPS - SSH gave the good error message) - yet having tried to reproduce this just now by pushing a big file to GitHub on my own Mac, I got the expected informative error message on both connection protocols (*"remote: error: File big is 976.56 MB; this exceeds GitHub's file size limit of 100 MB"*). It's possible that my colleague had an older version of Git installed that couldn't report the errors correctly.

If you decide you need to remove the large files from your Git history (as it's the only way you'll get them pushed up to GitHub), I can recommend [The BFG](http://rtyley.github.io/bfg-repo-cleaner/):

```
$ java -jar bfg.jar  --strip-blobs-bigger-than 50M  my-repo.git
```

*Full disclosure: I'm the author of the BFG Repo-Cleaner.*

Comment: After more investigation it's definitely something to do with file size. It's odd as GitHub states you will get proper error messages with large files https://help.github.com/articles/working-with-large-files

Answer (score 10):

Simple solution is to increase the HTTP post buffer size to allow for larger chunks to be pushed up to the remote repo. To do that, simply type:

```
git config http.postBuffer 52428800
```

The number is in bytes, so in this case I have set it to 50MB. The default is 1MB.

Comment: This fix will only apply to git/GitHub connections over http(s).  The OP's access is via ssh.

Comment: After doing this a was able to push to Github a large set of commits (61k objects), using an SSH connection.

Comment: I've changed my remote URL from SSH to HTTPS -- in order to see effect from `git config http.postBuffer 52428800` -- and it worked! To change your remote URL do: `git remote set-url my-upstream-remote https://github.com/OWNER/REPOSITORY.git`

Answer (score 3):

If you couldn't start the proccess it could also mean that permissions of your master server repository are wrong. I've just faced this problem, and my repository on master was with root.root permissions, so my user git couldn't write data there.

You may try checking your master's repository permissions before trying to push.

Comment: Exactly!  I got this error for that reason as well. One should of course make sure that the (probably) new repo folder is owned by git and run  "sudo chown -R <repo folder name>" if not

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. I was adding huge datasets (8.2, 2.3, 3.5 GB as zip) to the repo. All I had to do is to push those files one at a time instead of pushing all 15GB together.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Had this problem with bitbucket for hours.
My solution was to enter into the server via ssh and do a git clone of the project from there.

Answer (score 0):

https://stackoverflow.com/a/23987039/4151626

`git pull --depth=1`
`git fetch --unshallow`

If the `--unshallow` doesn't work, then just bump the depth high enough to cover the depth of history needed, ... e.g. `git pull --depth=1000`.