# Pull updates with git after cloned with --depth 1

Tags: git

This morning I made a shallow clone of the Linux sources

```
git clone --depth 1 https://github.com/torvalds/linux.git
```

which resulted in a `linux` folder of 851Mb.

Now I would like to pull the latest changes, but

```
git pull
```

starts a seemly huge download. After 60Mb I'm at 3% which extrapolates to 2Gb. However, the 5 commits since my clone change only a bunch of lines.

Am I doing something wrong? What are the 2Gb that `git` tries to download?

Comment: Strange...I did the same commands and [verified the size](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8185326/1079354) of what I had downloaded to be about 135MB.  I also did the same pull and nothing new was downloaded.  Which version of Git are you using?  I'm on 1.9.1 and am unable to reproduce your error.

Comment: @Makoto My sentence about the downloaded size was missleading/wrong. I've edited it now. Probably the actual download in my case was 135Mb, too. I am also using git version 1.9.1.

Comment: @Makoto If I clone the latest version, and then pull, I also just get `Already up-to-date`. So I suppose the problem only occurs if changes have been made to the remote repository since the clone.

Answer (score 92, accepted):

I think you can use `--depth 1` in `git pull` too, so it gets just what's needed for the newest commit in the repository.

I don't know if the default behaviour is to pull everything missing, because my `git help pull` shows this option:

```
git pull --unshallow
```

or

```
git fetch  --unshallow
```

> --unshallow
>              Convert a shallow repository to a complete one, removing all the limitations imposed by shallow repositories.

I'm running `git version 1.8.5.2 (Apple Git-48)`, and maybe this is some sort-of-new behaviour, and changing a bit between versions.

Comment: I've tried `git pull --depth 1` now. (Before I checked `git status` and everything showed clean.) Then the pull tried to merge something but failed at some point. Now `git status` shows `Unmerged paths`. `git pull` and `git checkout` do not work any more.

Comment: `git pull` / `git fetch` have `--unshallow` option

Comment: This always gets me. I do `git clone repo.git --depth=1`, then I forget about it, I `git log` and I'm amazed that there are too few commits. Then finally I remember that I've previously used `depth` option. `git pull --unshallow` saved my life all the time. Thanks!

Comment: If I try `pull --depth 1` on a linux kernel repository I eventually get "fatal: refusing to merge unrelated histories" and unshallow takes a lot of time to be useful. I end up just deleting the whole thing and cloning it again since it's faster.

Comment: `--unshallow` seems does not pull all branches, had to delete the repo and clone again without `--depth 1` option

Answer (score 7):

Could any of the new commits be merge-commits pointing to commits not present in your tree? Perhaps `--depth 1000` would work better and still be small enough.

Comment: Most of them seem to be merge commits. I'll try if some depth helps.

Comment: I do not fully understand how `--depth` works. Intuitively I would assume `--depth 1000` includes the last 1000 commits. But I tried `--depth 100` and end up with > 50000 commits reaching back to 2012.

Comment: Finally a new commit (tack Linus!) so I could test it. It works: having cloned with `--depth 100` `git pull` works fine (950Mb from `clone`, same after `pull`), while `--depth 1` leads to significantly larger repository size after the `pull`

Comment: That definitely explains why a linux kernel repo fails to pull with depth 1. Linus keeps merging from the trees of others. I don't fully get why more depth would help in that case but I guess it might.

Answer (score 5):

Depth places commits in the `.git/shallow` file.  When retrieving commit history, your request will stop at the commits in the shallow file, but if there were a merge into the current branch, it will follow that and the whole history behind it.

From my blog post, [Exploring Git Clone --depth](https://medium.com/@thriving_chiffon_gnu_714/exploring-git-clone-depth-828eb4bac6c4):

If you had a branch structure that you did a `git clone --depth=1` when main was at `c`:

```
...  -  .  -  .  - [c] -  .  -  .  -  .  -  .  (main)
         \               /
           .  -  .  -  .  (xyz)
```

And then later did a fetch at `g`, the merge at d would cause you to pull nearly the whole history (except `b`).

```
1000’s of commits  -  a  -  .  - [c] -  d  -  e  -  f  -  g  (main)
                       \               /
                         x  -  y  -  z  (xyz)
```

My blog post gives 2 suggestions for this:

1. Fetch with a specified depth and update your branch:

```
git fetch --depth 1 origin main
git reset --hard origin/main
```

2. Clone with enough history that you probably won't get bypasses:

```
git clone --shallow-since=2022-06-01 repo
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use

```
git pull --depth=50
```

or specify the depth you would like to download. That should be fine.