# git pull, ignores depth, how not to pull the entire history?

Tags: git

We have a massive multi GB git repo which is mainly binary objects.

It takes days to clone.

The actual master branch (without history) is only about 20MB, so a git clone with a depth of 1 was the cure, I thought.

However, Now I need to pull someones updates to the master (we have no branches), and when I pull, there is no depth option/parameter, so it downloads all 2GB.

Is there any way to pull only the master without the history?

I ama git noob (I only use tortoise git), but am expert at SVN, CVS etc.

Note 1: We used to use SVN, which has no such issues, but our rather nontechnical IT Director thought it would be good to impose git on the entire company, even those using mainly binary media, flash, js etc.

Note 2: I saw this post: [Pull updates with git after cloned with --depth 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23986685/pull-updates-with-git-after-cloned-with-depth-1) but I did not understand it.

Comment: What you are trying should work, unless (as the linked question) points out, some of the commits you are trying to merge reference commits which you haven't cloned. Is this the case? Also: you almost ticked off every box in the "When git is not for you" checklist.

Comment: The problem is if you pull a change AFTER you do a git clone --depth 1, it ignores the depth and pulls the entire history.  My question, is how do you PULL without the history.