# git: keep depth=1 on pulls to reduce repo size

Tags: git

Is there a way to make `git pull` keep `depth=1`, just use the latest commit, instead of the one that git clone was made (if there is newer one)?

I I do `git clone -b some_branch --depth=1 git_repo.git`

It clones the repository with minimum space usage because it removes all the history.
Now if I need to update that repository again and use `git pull`, it pulls the whole history.

**There is a similar question here:**

> [Pull updates with git after cloned with --depth 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23986685/pull-updates-with-git-after-cloned-with-depth-1)

If try accepted answer advice and use `git pull --unshallow` and then `git pull --depth=1`, it looks like it does not reduce space as `git clone --depth=1` does.

So the only way to really reduce repository size is to just remove repository and clone with `depth=1` again?. Looks kind of clunky way to do it.

And the reason I need this is that there are repositories used when fully cloned, currently take about `~3 GB` in size. And there are like 40 environments where it is used. So in total, it uses a lot of space. With a shallow clone, it can be reduced about 5 times.

**Sample:**

Cloning this repository branch 12.0 `git@github.com:odoo/odoo.git`, shows its size to be around 3 GB.

Cloning this repository branch 12.0 with `depth=1`, shows size to be 643 MB.

Using `--unshallow` on pull and then (as suggested here [Converting git repository to shallow?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4698759/converting-git-repository-to-shallow)):

```
git pull --depth 1
git gc --prune=all
```

Does not seem to shrink size as shallow clone does.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Converting git repository to shallow?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4698759/converting-git-repository-to-shallow)

Comment: @EncryptedWatermelon Most upvoted answer seems to not work in all cases. I tried pruning biggest repository and it did not shrink in size at all. Though, another repository that is smaller in size, did shrink. I also tried suggestions in comments, but that did not change anything.

Comment: @Andrius: read *all* the comments on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40452701/1256452). Also, see [VonC's answer there](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53245223/1256452) and make sure your Git version is up-to-date enough.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, the answer is "no".  Depth places commits in the `.git/shallow` file.  When retrieving commit history, your request will stop at the commits in the shallow file, but if there were a merge into the current branch, it will follow that and the whole history behind it.  From my blog post, [Exploring Git Clone --depth](https://medium.com/@thriving_chiffon_gnu_714/exploring-git-clone-depth-828eb4bac6c4):

If you had a branch structure that you did a `git clone --depth=1` when main was at `c`:

```
...  -  .  -  .  - [c] -  .  -  .  -  .  -  .  (main)
         \               /
           .  -  .  -  .  (xyz)
```

And then later did a fetch at `g`, the merge at d would cause you to pull nearly the whole history (except `b`).

```
1000’s of commits  -  a  -  .  - [c] -  d  -  e  -  f  -  g  (main)
                       \               /
                         x  -  y  -  z  (xyz)
```

The above medium blog post gives some suggestions, but no answer to your question.