# Broken Pipe during Git Push to Openshift from Netbeans

Tags: git, openshift, netbeans-8, openshift-client-tools

I recently tried deploy a Java  application to openshift from Netbeans 8.0 ,Git 1.9.1, Ubuntu 14.04  using Wildfly 9.0 and MongoDb catridges. The application was successfully deployed and hosted on Openshift . However i had to make some changes to the code, then push to the openshift server . While doing that, I had this error :

```
Pushing to ssh://57735e6c89f5cf85a700002f@firstapp-emsproj.rhcloud.com/~/git/firstapp.git/
Counting objects: 124, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (70/70), done.
Writing objects:  72% (66/91), 5.72 MiB | 12.00 KiB/s
Write failed: Broken pipe/91), 608.00 KiB | 397.00 KiB/s
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
error: pack-objects died of signal 13
error: failed to push some refs to 'ssh://57735e6c89f5cf85a700002f@firstapp-emsproj.rhcloud.com/~/git/firstapp.git/'
```

Any ideas on what could be wrong? why does the writing objects process stop at 72%. I had tried to push from netbeans but rather it throws a timeout error.

Answer (score 0):

If a `git config http.postBuffer 52428800` does not help, that could mean one of your commit is *really* too big (or your Openshift disk is full).

As described in "[Can't push to GitHub error: pack-objects died of signal 13](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18560284/6309)", you might want to remove from your local repo history any big files.

That last link was for GitHub, but [Openshift has some disk quota as well](https://developers.openshift.com/managing-your-applications/filesystem.html#git).

Answer (score 0):

I tried the above suggestion but had the same issues. Eventually after reading other posts , I realised that it was when i tried to push a large file that the problem started .  So I deleted the application on openshift , created another one , rebuilt the application from my system and did another push. This time it worked and it was deployed .