# git throwing broken pipe error on push

Tags: git

I'm getting a vague error from git when I'm trying to push a single commit, replacing a large file:

```
15:36:16.519: git push --progress origin master:master
/usr/bin/git-receive-pack:214:in `rewrite_refs_client_wants_to_modify': undefined method `sub' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
    from /usr/bin/git-receive-pack:92:in `block in start'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/2.1.0/open3.rb:199:in `popen_run'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/2.1.0/open3.rb:93:in `popen3'
    from /usr/bin/git-receive-pack:87:in `start'
    from /usr/bin/git-receive-pack:242:in `<main>'
Counting objects: 50, done.
Delta compression using up to 8 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (7/7), done.
fatal: sha1 file '<stdout>' write error: Broken pipe
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@git.assembla.com:project.git'
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Broken pipe when pushing to git repository](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19120120/broken-pipe-when-pushing-to-git-repository)

Comment: Tried answer, doesnt help, updated description.

Comment: Do you have enough space left on your disk? Do you have proper permissions to write the file?

Comment: Yes to both questions.

Comment: Try upgrading your Ruby package and see if the error still exists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was an issue on the repository server. I reached out to the service and they fixed it for me.