# Pushing to git repository located on an RDP client

Tags: git, macos, rdp

I have a bare local git repository on my laptop (OSX) that I treat as the origin for a clone located on a remote (Window 7) virtual machine over remote desktop (RDP).

To start, I redirected the laptop repository folder in the RDP configuration so it looks like a folder to the virtual machine. With this I have no problem cloning and pulling from the laptop repo. But when I try to push I get the following error:

```
C:\Proj\repo>git push origin
Counting objects: 9, done.
Delta compression using up to 2 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (9/9), done.
remote: error: insufficient permission for adding an object to repository database ./objects
remote: fatal: failed to write object
fatal: sha1 file '<stdout>' write error: Broken pipe
error: failed to push some refs to '//tsclient/bare_for_rdp'
```

Despite the error, I don't think it is a permission issue on the laptop, since I have made the entire directory world writable. (`chmod -R a+w *`). See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6448242/1224158)

Also I don't think the broken pipe has any thing to do with [buffer size issues](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19120120/1224158) since there are no particularly big files.

**Any ideas for how to get this to work?**

- Microsoft RDP: Version 8.0.6 (Build 24869)
- Remote (VM) git: 2.5.3.windows.1
- OSX: Mavericks (OS X 10.9.5 (13F1112))

Comment: Whatever your problem, making your files globally writable is never a good solution. You should probably revert that particular change.

Comment: @tripleee: Done. Thanks.

Comment: I was reading the other day trying to solve this problem because it’s came up a lot in my life and there’s a way it seems like to open up an rdp connection from the command line? I haven’t had enough time to figure it out but maybe someone can - worth a shot: https://www.google.com/amp/techgenix.com/usingremotedesktopclientcommandprompt/amp/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, I was able to work-around the problem by accessing our GitHub enterprise directly from the remote machine. This required working through some connectivity issues with the IT team, but is now working well.

Still curious about more direct ways to commit over RDP and will gladly change acceptance to a good, more direct answer to the original question.

Comment: Thank you for your follow-up. I'm also curious if there is a more decentralized solution for the work I'm doing on an RDP machine.

Comment: I am currently running into this issue as well. If we clone a repo on a folder inside the rdp, then move it to a mounted folder we can access the files on the local machine. I am able to edit the files, commit, then go back to the rdp to push the folder back up. Doing this allows me to edit and run code locally. The only issue I have come upon is keeping the git repo up-to-date with git pull. I read in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/750765/concurrency-in-a-git-repo-on-a-network-shared-folder/751026 that the issue lies with git locking files. Dropbox might be the best solution.