# How to resume a large commit pull?

Tags: git, large-files

Our remote team has recently pushed a large commit (40GB, 1800 files) of various assets to our repo. I tried to do a git pull and it was going fine until 15 hours later when i got a broken pipe error.
I searched SO for similar questions, but so far most of them involve cloning a large repo. I am not a git expert, so if there's some obvious solution I'm missing, please forgive me. Is there any way to safely pull this commit? Or "resume" if it fails?

Comment: Just educate your remote team on differences between VCS and Cloud Storage. Commit with 40GB and 1800 files should be removed from the repository.

Comment: @xenteros It's a statutory requirement to ship the product with the (educational) content in some locations. We did know it was too large, but it needed to be done.

Comment: The advice for cloning a large repo will apply to pulling.

Comment: @tymtam If I understand correctly, LFS is for a singular large file, isn't it? Each file in the commit is just about 15-50 MB in size, but collectively they are 40GB in size.

Answer (score 0):

Git pull or clone don't have resume functionaly.

You could:

1. Ask the person who already has a version of the repo with this commit to provide you with a copy of the repo through some other means (network share?).
2. try downloading the repo as a `zip`, if your git host allows this. The download client (web browser?) may able to deal with network issues better.
3. retry with `git config --global http.postBuffer 524288000` (From [Not able to clone large repo code on git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48200429/not-able-to-clone-large-repo-code-on-git), and [Broken pipe when pushing to git repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19120120/broken-pipe-when-pushing-to-git-repository)).

Comment: `http.postBuffer` has no effect on fetches or clones, only pushes, and it should only be used with known broken servers or proxies that don't support `Transfer-Encoding: chunked`.