# git push to github fails with "error: pack-objects died of signal 967"

Tags: git, github

I fired this command:

```
git push origin master
```

I got this result:

```
Counting objects: 15626, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
error: pack-objects died of signal 967
error: pack-objects died with strange error
```

Comment: icheck this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18559015/cant-push-to-github-error-pack-objects-died-of-signal-13

Comment: and this : https://stackoverflow.com/q/8672949/2745495

Answer (score 1):

There is no signal number 967, but there *is* a signal number 9, which is `SIGKILL` on Linux and Unix systems.  I think something printed a line ending in `67`, then a carriage return, and then your local `git pack-objects` was hit by the "OOM killer".

What you need to do is give your Linux system (this is *your* system, not the one you're pushing to) more memory, or push smaller commits (or both).  "Memory" in this case can be real, physical RAM, or virtual memory: swap space to which your system can write otherwise-idle memory contents from mostly-idle programs that are sitting around hogging memory.  To get more physical memory, you can of course install more DRAM chips; or you can just exit any memory-hogging programs that you don't really need to keep running.

You can also tweak your Git's memory-usage settings, so that it takes less memory to do object compression, but usually there is no good reason to do that (unless you have a very old version of Git: newer ones detect enormous binary files and don't even *attempt* to compress them).

#### Details

When Git is doing a push, you normally see these:

```
Counting objects: nnnnn, done.
```

and:

```
Compressing objects:  nn% (mmmmm/nnnnn)
```

*progress messages*, to reassure you that Git is actually doing something during what otherwise might seem to be a long pause.  These come from `git pack-objects`, which `git push` runs to make what Git calls a *thin pack*, to send to the other Git to which you're pushing data.

Your Git actually finished the "counting objects" phase and had entered the "compressing objects" phase, which is more memory-intensive.

So, `git pack-objects` is merrily printing progress lines:

```
Compressing objects:  xx% (xxxxx/xxx69)
```

It sends the cursor back to the start of the line after each printout, so that the next line overwrites the previous one, so that eventually it will say "100% (nnnnn/nnnnn), done."  (And once it gets to that point it prints a newline, not just a carriage return.)

Sadly, at this point Linux—or whatever system you are using—decided that too many programs were using too much memory, and chose `git pack-objects` as the victim for its Out Of Memory killing.  It killed off `git pack-objects` with `SIGKILL`, signal 9.

This made your push print:

```
error: pack-objects died of signal 9
```

atop the previous progress line, leaving:

```
error: pack-objects died of signal 967)
```

(Note: I don't know what the digits for all the `x`-s were, except that they must necessarily end in `67`.  The error message is *not* prefixed by `remote:`, but *should* end with `signal 967)`—i.e., a string with a closing parenthesis—and not just `signal 967`.)

The OOM killer means your system is low on memory.  The fact that it picked `git pack-objects` as its victim does not necessarily mean that `git pack-objects` itself is the *reason* your system ran out of memory. It was just the biggest fish the system saw in the overfull fish-tank.  Linux chooses to take out that one, rather than taking out five smaller fish.

Comment: Phenomenal answer! Such insight and clear detail. Thank you.