# Aggressive git GC failing with signal 99019 from pack-objects?

Tags: git

I am trying to cut down the size of a currently 11GB repository (.git itself is 3.9GB, the rest is 7.1GB), and `git gc` has worked okay (that brought it down from 14GB originally), but when I try `git gc --aggressive` to go further:

```
root@host:/path/to/repo# git gc --aggressive
Counting objects: 221534, done.
Delta compression using up to 8 threads.
error: pack-objects died of signal 99019)   
error: failed to run repack
```

What does signal 99019 mean? I haven't been able to find any documentation for pack-objects returning that code.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/4826639/242520 Look at pack and window size.

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/q/45397553/1256452 - it's actually "signal 9".